# Is it normal for to take several seconds to create a UIView and subviews?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` action that, when called, creates (totally in code) a `UITableView` with may 2 or 3 rows (nothing fancy), with a header and a footer, and make 2 or 3 simple `UILabels` in those. This `UITableView` is then added as a subview of the main view on active `UIViewController`. It takes about 3 seconds on the simulator for this action to execute and actually show this UITableView.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is definitely not normal.  You need to isolate exactly what is taking up all that time.  One pretty simple way to do that is sprinkle NSLog calls in various places in your code, so you can see what's getting called when.  That's probably good enough to get you started.

Eventually you probably want some more sophisticated timing code that you can use to profile things.  I use a variation of [this code](http://wafflesoftware.net/machtimer/documentation.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If you share your code, we can probably help you figure out what's going on. But you shouldn't have any problem like that if you're just responding to the methods outlined in the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) protocol in a timely manner:

- [numberOfRowsInSection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/numberOfRowsInSection%3a);
- [numberOfSections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/numberOfSections); and
- [cellForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a).